# wpf treat word as single "character"/element

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I have a custom text editor derived from RichTextBox where the user can drag an object into the box and it displays the object's name (amongst other, keyboard entered, text). I would like to treat this name as a single, uneditable, entity: the user can only delete the whole name and can't change anything on the inside.

I would also like the formatting to be completely isolated from the surroundings. Right now I insert it as a separate Run. Iff the user places the cursor at the end of the name, the new keyboard entered text has the name formatting which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, for anyone else trying to do something similar, I was able to do this by using an InlineUIContainer holding a TextBlock.